# Wordpress Feed Rss very slow to load

Tags: nginx, rss, wordpress, feed

I've a big website that use wordpress.
Today we have chagend the server with a 8-core with 32gb of ram at hetzner. We have installed Centos 6, Nginx, Php acp and fpm, Mysql.... but is born a problem.
The feed of the website load very very slow (give 504 timeout error) and the same thing doing the plugin json api.

Have you some idea for why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hello please increase php memory limit and try again

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP and Increase the amount of memory a PHP script may consume. Note: If using a shared hosting service, you may need to ask your host to increase the limit.
Increase the memory limit setting in php.ini (e.g. memory_limit = 64M ;). Many hosts may not allow this.
Increase the memory limit via .htaccess (e.g. php_value memory_limit 64M). Many hosts may not allow this.
Increase the memory limit via wp-config.php (e.g. define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');)